# Node.js as Rails replacement? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, replace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could node.js replace Ruby on Rails completely in the future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436335/could-node-js-replace-ruby-on-rails-completely-in-the-future)

I'm doing bad in understanding the sense of node.js. I understand what it does regarding IO etc., but is it for example a Ruby on Rails replacement? Can I do the same database operations etc.? What about authentication?

what kind of web or other applications get build on basis of node.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> is it for example a ruby on rails replacement?

IMHO RoR has much longer history/experience/functionality for website development. Node.js itself is a lightweight (low level) framework from which you can take off to build various types of server-side applications (not just web oriented). One of its main advantages is in wide spectrum of [modules](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules) provided by community of open source developers.

> Can i do the same database operations etc.?

Yes, just find the right module for your type of database.

> What about authentication?

Modules like [connect](http://senchalabs.github.com/connect/) offers built-in authentication functionality.

Answer (score 4):

Node.js is a totally separate technology to Ruby on Rails, built on a different technology stack. In its current state it's not a replacement for Rails, and certainly not a drop-in replacement

Comment: so for what kind of applications is node.js then?

Answer (score 4):

AIUI Node.js is a bit more low-level than that, in particular it has no support for typical high level web development (MVC model, db integration, etc). Look at it as a javascripty basis to write networking software on (including web frameworks).

There are some web frameworks out there built on Node.js. The only one I know is [geddy](http://geddyjs.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Node.JS is to Javascript as EventMachine is to Ruby (and Twisted to Python). It's something completely different from Rails.

To illustrate: the Thin webserver that is often used to serve Rails application was built using EventMachine. So you would need a complete web framework on top of Node.JS to make it a Rails replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing apples and pears.

Ruby on Rails is a MVC Framework to build websites.
Nodejs is a framework to build evented I/O operations.

You can build a port of RoR on top of nodejs if you want.